# Rest web service

Tags: iphone

I am aware of using the soap webservices on iphone .Now i want to use REST. Can anybody tell me, What are the methods associated with calling and use of rest webservice?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many ways accessing RESTful web services from the iPhone is extremely similar to accessing SOAP web services.  As your probably know, in a RESTful web service, you do not send an XML (or other data store) request.

You want to look at the following classes:

- NSURL
- NSMutableURLRequest
- NSURLConnection

Here is some sample code for making the RESTful request:

```
NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:@"theURLofTheWebService"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if(theConnection)
{
    webData = [[NSMutableData data]retain];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}
```

You also want to implement the following delegate methods of NSURLConnection:

- `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response`
- `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data`
- `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error`
- `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection`

Finally depending on the type of data returned (XML, JSON, etc.) you can use the appropriate ways to parse that data.